# How to fix circular dependency between functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, circular-dependency

I know that there are many questions of similar title like this. However, I read all of them and I cannot get to solve my problem. I've fallen in a circular dependency where I have those functions[each one defined in a dedicated module]:

- `generateNodeCode`
- `generateGroupCode`
- `generateContainerCode`

and the circle is closed by `generateNodeCode` referencing `generateGroupCode` which in turn referencing `generateGroupCode` which in turn referencing `generateContainerCode`.

To simplify the situation, look at this graph.
[image]

I know that I should refactor this to reach a better design but I do not know how.

Here is an example code:

generateNodeCode.js

```js
const { generateGroupCode } = require("./generateGroupCode");

function generateNodeCode(node) {
  switch(node.constructor.name) {
    // many cases
    case "Group":
      return generateGroupCode(node);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  generateNodeCode
};
```

generateGroupCode.js

```js
const { generateContainerCode } = require("./generateContainerCode");

function generateGroupCode(group) {
  // some stuff
  return generateContainerCode();
}

module.exports = {
  generateGroupCode
};
```

generateContainerCode.js

```js
const { generateNodeCode } = require("./generateNodeCode");

function generateContainerCode(children) {
  // some stuff
  children.forEach(child => {
    generateNodeCode();
  });
}

module.exports = {
  generateContainerCode
};
```

Comment: do you have an example with code?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with circular dependencies, as long as the recursion ends eventually.

Comment: The problem is that each one is separated in its own module so modules require each other @Barmar

Comment: They probably shouldn't be in separate modules.